# Componentheading and contentpagetitle joomla

Tags: templates, joomla

If have a problem with the componentheading and the contentpagetitle.

I got a sectionblog for my articles. The title of the page is a componentheading. The title of the articles (intro) is a contentpagetitle.

If I click on the title of a article, I can see the entire article. The title of the page is now the title of the article (contentpagetitle), and that is good.

The problem is, this title now needs the same layout as the componentheading. But if I do this, the titles of the articles also get this layout in the sectionblog

How can I make sure I got 2 different styles, or the contentpagetitle changes in a componentheading while looking at the full article?

I you don't uderstand what I'm saying just go to http://csm.infowebpreview.be/nl/realisaties, and click on the first title 'Realisatie'. The full article opens and the title 'Realisatie' should be underlined now.

Or this is also correct: if an article is the only article on a page the title should get another layout

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by being more specific with the CSS selector -

This one will apply to all of the titles, make this one the one for the main heading with the underline -

```
h2.contentheadingrealisaties{border-bottom: 1px solid #333}
```

Then use this to single out the article titles in a listing:

```
.leadingrealisaties h2.contentheadingrealisaties{border:0;}
```

Obviously you will need to add in the rest of the CSS, but this will get you started.

Comment: great that's it, I was looking for something to change in the title for the full realisatie, not the titles in the sectionblog, stupid me
. I can also use this for the news blog and some other Joomla sites I made. Thanks man

Comment: No problem. If you are using the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, or IE9 you can usually right click and select Inspect Element to get a ton of info about the CSS making it very easy to determine what selectors you need to use to customize specific elements. You can also use Firebug or Web Developer extension for Firefox.